# How to make read only (programmatically filled) Preferences?

Tags: android

How to make  Preferences items with programmatically filled values (like: Version, Model number...)?

Comment: Can you please select a "correct" answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the preferences within you code, and check if it already is filled before you fill it. As long as you do not give users access to change this information, all they can do is "clear local data", which will cause the program to re-fill the data if you do it right.

I use this technique to store unique IDs for the device, who is logged in, etc. The user doesn't even (and should never) know what I keep track of, all they know is they have a smooth program that does what they need it to do.

Example:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("preferanceName", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
int value = foo;
editor.putInt("ValueToStore", value);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make the item in "preferencses.xml" that will appear as "gray" (read-only) text without the possibility of interactive editing?

Comment: I make my own custom preference activity, so I couldn't really tell you. Sounds like another question for SO :D

Comment: @yuriy: Yes, you can make Preferences read-only by adding android:enabled="false" to the XML. See here for details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html

Comment: Thank you. With the addition of thу string {pref.setSummary(copyofPrefValue);} got what I need.

Answer (score 39):

Why not use android.preference.Preference directly?

```
<Preference 
 android:key="version"
 android:title="@string/version" />
```

No edit dialog, no more attribute, and information only!!

```
//Set the version string in your code 
findPreference("version").setSummary(version);
```

Comment: Any way to make this reflect the versionString in the manifest?

Comment: @scone String version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;

Comment: @tpbapp I was hoping for a way to do this without code.

Answer (score 26):

I accomplished this with the following:

In my application_preferences.xml I have the following preference.  This makes it so it is still black (not gray), but still cannot be edited by the user.  Making it gray makes it difficult to read.

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="version"
    android:title="@string/version"
    android:enabled="false" 
    android:selectable="false"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:shouldDisableView="false"/>
```

In the preference activity onCreate method, get the version preference and set the title to the application version.

```
EditTextPreference versionPref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("version");
String version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
versionPref.setTitle(getString(R.string.version) + ": " + version);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I did this using androidx, and if I had `persistent` set to `false`, the value would be displayed as `Not set`. Once I removed the `persistent` attribute it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Westwood it is perfect thanks!!

In my case I just change the **setTitle** to **setSummary**, so the value is visible bellow the title.

```
    String serverUrl = "http://...";
    EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("serverPrefKey");
    pref.setSummary(serverUrl);
```